# Assign if not null

Tags: c#, null

Being a fan of null-coalescing operator and the null-propagating operator, I would like to assign something if the object is not null.

Something like:

```
myArray.FirstOrDefault()?.Value = newValue;
```

Instead of:

```
var temp = myArray.FirstOrDefault()

if(temp != null){
     temp.Value = newValue;
}
```

Is this possible?

(I am aware I could use SetValue() )

Comment: Why you close this question by an answer of C# 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C# 8.0 you can do this

```
temp ??= newValue;
```